# UIDatePicker in a popover randomly doesn't update the first time but will every time after that

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker being shown in a popover. When I spin, half the time the value won't update, then it will every time after that. The other half, it updates the first time and every time after that - just as expected.

Scenario 1: tap, choose time, update, value updates, update again, value updates again... repeat.

Scenario 2: tap, choose time, update, value doesn't update, update again, value updates, update again, value updates... repeat.

At first, it was skipping the update the first time every time, then implementing [this answer's fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295013/uidate-picker-valuechanged-does-not-update-the-first-spin-but-does-every-spin-a) seemed to help until I used it more to see it only works now about half the time.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *datePickerController;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == kAddEditProductsTargetBatchTime) {
        [self setupDatePickerWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)setupDatePickerWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect cellFrame = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect popoverFrame = CGRectMake(cellFrame.size.width - 100.0f, cellFrame.origin.y, 50.0f, cellFrame.size.height);

    CGSize dpSize = CGSizeMake(200, 180);
    _datePickerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];

    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,dpSize.width, dpSize.height);
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
    datePicker.countDownDuration = 0;

    batchTarget *defaultCycleTarget = [cycleTargetRepository defaultCycleTarget:_product.cycleTargets]; //NSTimeInterval

    if (indexPath.row == kAddEditProductsTargetBatchTime) {
        NSDateComponents *dateComp = [NSDateComponents new];
        dateComp.hour = [NSNumberFormatter hoursComponent:defaultCycleTarget.targetBatchTime]; //NSTimeInterval
        dateComp.minute = [NSNumberFormatter minutesComponent:defaultCycleTarget.targetBatchTime]; //NSTimeInterval
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDate *pickerDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComp];

        [datePicker setDate:pickerDate animated: YES];
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(batchTimeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
    _datePickerController.view = datePicker;

    _datePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    _datePickerController.preferredContentSize = dpSize;
    [self presentViewController:_datePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    _datePickerController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = popoverFrame;
    _datePickerController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
}

//timeChanged doesn't even get fired off.. randomly && only on the first try
- (void)timeChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    batchTarget *defaultCycleTarget = [cycleTargetRepository defaultCycleTarget:_product.cycleTargets];
    if (defaultCycleTarget) {
        defaultCycleTarget.targetBatchTime = sender.countDownDuration;
    } else {
        // If no defaultCycleTarget we need to initialize the data
        batchTarget *newCycleTarget = [batchTarget new];
        newCycleTarget.targetBatchTime = sender.countDownDuration;
        _product.cycleTargets = [NSArray arrayWithObject:newCycleTarget];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I have essentially the [same exact code in a different view using Swift](https://gist.github.com/NickCalabs/7ccea493a7fa467789645a3efebb1dea) and experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like iOS buffer issues.

try to change the runloop and make the multiple of 60 secs. It works for me.

```
- (void) someMethodName
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(sel:) withObject:datePicker afterDelay:0];
}

- (void) sel:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
{
    datePicker.countDownDuration = 60;
}
```

Comment: So I add `[self performSelector:@selector(setDuration:) withObject:datePicker afterDelay:0];` to `setupDatePickerWithIndexPath` and `- (void)setDuration:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker { datePicker.countDownDuration = 60; }`. This made the problem worse in that it _always_ takes two spins to update now.